# Run Macro in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I'm doing a project that allow the customer to export the mysql data into .xls form. I'm using phpspreadsheet library.
That's done, but in my data contain lots of date, some of the date is 0000-00-00 means that it is not used.

I wanted to filter all of these '0000-00-00' into '-'.
I uses excel find and replace and save them as macro ( .bas )

What i have tried is

1. load the .bas file with IOFactory and reader in php, but it say the file format is not accepted
2. use substitute method in php loops that use to get the sql data value
     `$activeSheet->setCellValue('L'.$i, '=substitute('L'.$i ,"0000-00-00", "-')');`

   $i is 1 that will increase by 1 for each loop
   This method failed when the i can't include the `$i` inside the `substitute()` because the of "" and
   '' problem, I tried to change them around, but seem like the `0000-00-00` and `-` must use `""`, if
   not the method is not recognise by the library that makes the `$i` can't be detect then...

   Is there any way to solve any of these problems? or it can't be solve in the first place?
   cause i can't found any explanation of macro in phpspreadsheet from community nor google.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the value of the cell

```
 if ($datefromselect == '0000-00-00') {
    $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($colnum, $rownum, '-');
 } else {
    $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($colnum, $rownum, $datefromselect);
 }
```

or get it done in the select as in

```
SELECT lastname, 
if(date_closed = '0000-00-00', '-', date_closed) 
FROM `lca_clients`
```